# express + hogan how to handle session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, hogan.js

I use `expressjs` and `hoganjs` below is my `package.json` and setup . I have question if I have to detect session and give different layout inside `Index.hjs` only a part.
What should I do?

I can't find any document about session in `hoganjs`, it seems only handle template logic-less?
So does that mean I have to detect in `routes/Index.js` and render different file? How to do this any example?

And if I have to make two file have duplicate part, then I tried to find a way like extend, include method so I found [load other template file inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601578/how-to-load-templates-with-hogan-js-from-an-external-file) but it seems so not convenience, so I'm wondering usually people how to do this?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "pg": "^4.4.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
// end: view engine setup

...

// route handler to each routes
require('./RouteHandler.js')(app, express);
// end: route handler to each routes
...
```

RouteHandler.js

```
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var setupRoutes = function(app, express) {
  // uncomment after placing your favicon in /assets
  //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));


  var routesIndex = require('./routes/Index');
  var routesAccount = require('./routes/Account');

  app.use('/', routesIndex);
  app.use('/account', routesAccount);

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  });
}


module.exports = setupRoutes;
```

routes/Index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  ...

  res.render('Index/Index', { title: 'Express' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Index.hjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- session exist -->
    <!-- logged in layout -->
    <!-- end: session exist -->

    <!-- session exist -->
    <!-- logged out layout -->
    <!-- end: session exist -->

    ... both 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find any document about session in hoganjs, it seems only handle template?

[Hogan](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) is template engine. *All it does is process templates.* You are correct. (See: [*what is a template engine?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547028/what-is-a-template-engine))

> So does that mean I have to detect in routes/Index.js and render different file?

*Nope.*

What you should do is, render *one* template but in that template, show the menu items *conditionally*:

```
{{#user}}
  <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
{{/user}}

{{^user}}
  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
{{/user}}
```

In Hogan, you can express what is equivalent to an `if` statement using the above syntax. (See: [*Hogan If Statements*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970516/hogan-js-if-statements).)

You need some way to pass the `user` instance to the template if there is one. You can do that in a route handler:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
     res.render('home', { user: req.user });
   } else { 
     res.render('home');
   }
});
```

Or in the likely case that you want to show the menu on every page - probably in a layout - you can create [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
  }
  next();
});
```

In the above examples, I am using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) middleware. You are going to need to implement your own identity and authentication system but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank for explanation!!

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user1775888 Thank you :3.

Answer (score 1):

`Hogan` does not handle session. Express does that. You will need to have a session store which will let you store stuff you want in the `req` object.
Based on the value you store, you can pass the value to the template and load what ever.

Session store - https://github.com/expressjs/session

In `Index.js`

// set value

`req.session.user.loggedIn = true;`

// pass to template

`res.render('Index/Index', { title: 'Express', 'loggedIn': req.session.user.loggedIn });`

```
// in template            
if (loggedIn) {
 <p>Logged in</p>
} else {
 <p>Not logged in</p>
}
```

**Edit** - added details

Comment: so if I have different html dom  for login and logout , then I have to mark up html in `routes/index.js` then pass to template?

Comment: Thank for explanation